# presto error "Hive table '' is corrupt. Found sub-directory in bucket directory for partition"?

Tags: hive, presto, flume, flume-ng

I have already disabled hive transaction by setting "hive.txn.manager=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.lockmgr.DummyTxnManager" according to the [site](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/Enable-disable-ACID/ta-p/245188).

But when i queryed by presto, it still showed the exception message like "Hive table '' is corrupt. Found sub-directory in bucket directory for partition".

I found that if i insert table manually, presto's query on this table returns ok.But if the table was inserted by flume, presto's query on this table would fail.

My manual sql is like below.

```
INSERT INTO test_flume6 PARTITION (area = 'x', business='x', 
minuteTime='y') VALUES (201,'x','x');
```

My presto version is [0.229](https://prestodb.io/download.html), my hive version is hive-1.1.0-cdh5.9.0.
My flume version is flume-ng-1.6.0-cdh5.9.0.

My flume's hiveSink configuration is like below.

```
# Hive Sink
agent.sinks.hive_sink.type = hive
agent.sinks.hive_sink.hive.metastore = thrift://hive:9083
agent.sinks.hive_sink.hive.database = estate
agent.sinks.hive_sink.hive.table = test_flume6
#agent.sinks.hive_sink.hive.txnsPerBatchAsk = 2
agent.sinks.hive_sink.hive.partition = asia,stock,%y-%m-%d-%H-%M
#agent.sinks.hive_sink.batchSize = 10
agent.sinks.hive_sink.serializer = DELIMITED
agent.sinks.hive_sink.serializer.delimiter = ,
agent.sinks.hive_sink.serializer.fieldnames = id,username,email
```

My hive table's creation sql is like below.

```
create table test_flume6(
`id` string,
username string,
email string
)
PARTITIONED BY(area string, business string, minuteTime string)
clustered by(id)
into 5 buckets
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\u0001'
stored as orc
TBLPROPERTIES ('transactional'='false');
```

Comment: Presto 327 (https://prestosql.io/download.html) brings a number of improvements around handling of hive bucketed tables (transactional or not). Do you get the same error when using Presto 327?

Comment: BTW troubleshooting is not really best fit for SO. I recommend you use `#troubleshooting` on [Presto community slack](https://prestosql.io/slack.html).